# getting error: expected ':' before '*' token in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i am trying to devlope one RSSFeed application from http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial. everything was going well till this error occurs. i have checked everything in tutorial code but couldn't find anything. i have copied the code as it is. i have stuck here & wanted to get rid off it so i can go further & work get done. i am putting the piece of code below. please anyone can help me with it.
                        thnx in advance..

```
//  RootViewController.m
//  RSSFun

#import "GDataXMLNode.h"
#import "GDataXMLElement-Extras.h"
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import "RSSEntry.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"


@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize feeds = _feeds;
@synthesize queue = _queue;

@synthesize allEntries = _allEntries;

- (void)refresh {
for (NSString *feed in _feeds) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:feed];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [_queue addOperation:request];
}    
}

- (void)addRows {    
RSSEntry *entry1 = [[[RSSEntry alloc] initWithBlogTitle:@"1" 
                                           articleTitle:@"1" 
                                             articleUrl:@"1" 
                                            articleDate:[NSDate date]] autorelease];
RSSEntry *entry2 = [[[RSSEntry alloc] initWithBlogTitle:@"2" 
                                           articleTitle:@"2" 
                                             articleUrl:@"2" 
                                            articleDate:[NSDate date]] autorelease];
RSSEntry *entry3 = [[[RSSEntry alloc] initWithBlogTitle:@"3" 
                                           articleTitle:@"3" 
                                             articleUrl:@"3" 
                                            articleDate:[NSDate date]] autorelease];    

[_allEntries insertObject:entry1 atIndex:0];
[_allEntries insertObject:entry2 atIndex:0];
[_allEntries insertObject:entry3 atIndex:0];        
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];    
self.title = @"Feeds";
self.allEntries = [NSMutableArray array];
self.queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
self.feeds = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://feeds.feedburner.com/RayWenderlich",
              @"http://feeds.feedburner.com/vmwstudios",
              @"http://idtypealittlefaster.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default", 
              @"http://www.71squared.com/feed/",
              @"http://cocoawithlove.com/feeds/posts/default",
              @"http://feeds2.feedburner.com/brandontreb",
              @"http://feeds.feedburner.com/CoryWilesBlog",
              @"http://geekanddad.wordpress.com/feed/",
              @"http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default",
              @"http://karnakgames.com/wp/feed/",
              @"http://kwigbo.com/rss",
              @"http://shawnsbits.com/feed/",
              @"http://pocketcyclone.com/feed/",
              @"http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/feed/",         
              @"http://feeds.feedburner.com/maniacdev",
              @"http://feeds.feedburner.com/macindie",
              nil];    
[self refresh];
}


 /*
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
*/

/*
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
*/

/*
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
*/

 /*

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
*/

 /*
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
*/

/*
 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations.
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
 */

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
// Release anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
//Error occurs here
[_queue addOperationWithBlock:^
{

    NSError *error;
    GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:[request responseData] 
                                                           options:0 error:&error];
    if (doc == nil) { 
        NSLog(@"Failed to parse %@", request.url);
    } else {

        NSMutableArray *entries = [NSMutableArray array];
        [self parseFeed:doc.rootElement entries:entries];                

        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

            for (RSSEntry *entry in entries) {

                int insertIdx = 0;                    
                [_allEntries insertObject:entry atIndex:insertIdx];
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertIdx inSection:0]]
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

            }                            

        }];

    }        
}];

}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
NSError *error = [request error];
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}

- (void)parseFeed:(GDataXMLElement *)rootElement entries:(NSMutableArray *)entries {    
if ([rootElement.name compare:@"rss"] == NSOrderedSame) {
    [self parseRss:rootElement entries:entries];
} else if ([rootElement.name compare:@"feed"] == NSOrderedSame) {                       
    [self parseAtom:rootElement entries:entries];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Unsupported root element: %@", rootElement.name);
}    
}

- (void)parseRss:(GDataXMLElement *)rootElement entries:(NSMutableArray *)entries {

NSArray *channels = [rootElement elementsForName:@"channel"];
for (GDataXMLElement *channel in channels) {            

    NSString *blogTitle = [channel valueForChild:@"title"];                    

    NSArray *items = [channel elementsForName:@"item"];
    for (GDataXMLElement *item in items) {

        NSString *articleTitle = [item valueForChild:@"title"];
        NSString *articleUrl = [item valueForChild:@"link"];            
        NSString *articleDateString = [item valueForChild:@"pubDate"];        
        NSDate *articleDate = nil;

        RSSEntry *entry = [[[RSSEntry alloc] initWithBlogTitle:blogTitle 
                                                  articleTitle:articleTitle 
                                                    articleUrl:articleUrl 
                                                   articleDate:articleDate] autorelease];
        [entries addObject:entry];

    }      
}

}

- (void)parseAtom:(GDataXMLElement *)rootElement entries:(NSMutableArray *)entries {

NSString *blogTitle = [rootElement valueForChild:@"title"];                    

NSArray *items = [rootElement elementsForName:@"entry"];
for (GDataXMLElement *item in items) {

    NSString *articleTitle = [item valueForChild:@"title"];
    NSString *articleUrl = nil;
    NSArray *links = [item elementsForName:@"link"];        
    for(GDataXMLElement *link in links) {
        NSString *rel = [[link attributeForName:@"rel"] stringValue];
        NSString *type = [[link attributeForName:@"type"] stringValue]; 
        if ([rel compare:@"alternate"] == NSOrderedSame && 
            [type compare:@"text/html"] == NSOrderedSame) {
            articleUrl = [[link attributeForName:@"href"] stringValue];
        }
    }

    NSString *articleDateString = [item valueForChild:@"updated"];        
    NSDate *articleDate = nil;

    RSSEntry *entry = [[[RSSEntry alloc] initWithBlogTitle:blogTitle 
                                              articleTitle:articleTitle 
                                                articleUrl:articleUrl 
                                               articleDate:articleDate] autorelease];
    [entries addObject:entry];

}      

}


#pragma mark Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section              {
return [_allEntries count];

}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSString *articleDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:entry.articleDate];

cell.textLabel.text = entry.articleTitle;        
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", articleDateString, entry.blogTitle];

return cell;

}


/*

// Override to support row selection in the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Navigation logic may go here -- for example, create and push another view controller.
// AnotherViewController *anotherViewController = [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherView" bundle:nil];
// [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];


// [anotherViewController release];
}
*/
/*

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
}

*/


/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source.
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}   
else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
}   
}

*/


/*

  // Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
 }
*/




 // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
return YES;
}

 */


- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
[_allEntries release];
_allEntries = nil;
[_queue release];
_queue = nil;
[_feeds release];
_feeds = nil;


}


@end
```

Comment: Why post the whole code? Can you give just line that gives error + may be **few** lines that may be relevant?

Comment: Please can you at least let us know the line that is giving the error? Copy it out separately and include the whole file after your question as an FYI, if you think it's relevant.

Comment: This isn't a *do my work for me* site.

Comment: - (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
 //Error occurs here
    [_queue addOperationWithBlock:^
 {
  
        NSError *error;
        GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:[request responseData]

Answer (score 3):

Just before your dealloc method you have a spurious */ which needs removing.

Comment: I always use `//*/` as the comment closing so that I just need to remove the comment opening when I need to uncomment the blocks. Works all the time.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`Right at teh end of your file you have the following:

```
 // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



// Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
return YES;
}

 */
```

That last end comment block */ should be removed as it has no start block. leaving:

```
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
    }
```